# Need to cover Else if part in test class

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex

I covered 1st six condition but after that i am not able to increase my code coverage.Plz help.

Apex class:

```
if(acc1.Domain_Name_Number__c == 0 && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && acc1.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Status check about - Domain Name',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_7__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Domain_Name_Number__c == 0 && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 14 && acc1.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'How-to Email about - Domain Name',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_14__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Domain_Name_Number__c == 0 && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 21 && acc1.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {

                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Best Practices Email about - Domain Name',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_21__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Payments_Enabled_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && acc1.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {

                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Status check about - Payment Enabled',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_7__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Payments_Enabled_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 14 && acc1.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'How-to Email about- Payment Enabled',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_14__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Payments_Enabled_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 21 && acc1.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {                        
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Best Practices Email about - Payment Enabled',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_21__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true; 
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                         t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Status check about - Logistics Enabled',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_7__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 14 && acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'How-to Email about - Logistics Enabled',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_14__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 21 && acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {                          
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Best Practices Email about - Logistics Enabled',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_21__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                         else if(acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Status check about - Webstore Products Uploaded',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_7__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 14 && acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'How-to Email about - Webstore Products Uploaded',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_14__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                                 acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Checkbox__c = true;
                             }
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 21 && acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Best Practices Email about - Webstore Products Uploaded',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_21__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Products_Uploaded_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Checkbox__c == false )
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Status check about - Webstore Images Uploaded',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_7__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                                 acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 14 && acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'How-to Email about - Webstore Images Uploaded',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_14__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 21 && acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {

                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Best Practices Email about - Webstore Images Uploaded',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_21__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Images_Uploaded_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Status check about - Webstore Product Descriptions',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_7__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                              acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 14 && acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'How-to Email about - Webstore Product Descriptions',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_14__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 21 && acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Best Practices Email about - Webstore Product Descriptions',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_21__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Product_Descriptions_Checkbox__c = true;
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Pages_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && acc1.WebStore_Pages_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Status check about - Webstore Pages',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_7__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Pages_Checkbox__c = true; 
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Pages_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 14 && acc1.WebStore_Pages_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {
                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'How-to Email about - Webstore Pages',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_14__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                             acc1.WebStore_Pages_Checkbox__c = true; 
                          }
                          else if(acc1.WebStore_Pages_Number__c == 0  && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 21 && acc1.WebStore_Pages_Checkbox__c == false)
                          {

                             t = new Task( 
                                 whatID = acc1.id,
                                 Subject = 'Best Practices Email about - Webstore Pages',
                                 ownerID = acc1.ownerID,
                                 On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email',
                                 Description = acc1.Merchant_Segment_21__c
                                 );
                                 ltask1.add(t);   
                              acc1.WebStore_Pages_Checkbox__c = true; 
                          }
```

Test class:

```
@istest(seeAlldata=false)
public class TestMerchantLifecycleSchedulerClass { 

     public static testMethod void TestMefordiffAges(){
        test.startTest();

        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName1 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt1 = rtName1.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();

        Account a=new Account();
        a.LastName='TestAcc1';
        a.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-1;
        a.Login_Log_Count_0_30__c = 1; 
        a.Website_Published__c = true;
        insert a;
        a.Merchant_Engagement__c = 'Not Engaged';
        a.Merchant_Webstore_Status__c = 'Completed';
        update a;

        task t=new task();
        t.whatid=A.id;
        t.Status='In Progress';
        insert t;

        Account aa=new Account();
        aa.LastName='TestAcc1';
        aa.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        aa.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-1;
        aa.Login_Log_Count_0_30__c = 5;
        aa.WebStore_Images_Uploaded__c= 1;
        aa.WebStore_Pages__c =0;
        aa.WebStore_Products_Uploaded__c =0;
        aa.WebStore_Product_Descriptions__c =0;
        aa.Domain_Name_Number__c =0;
        aa.Payments_Enabled_Number__c =0;
        aa.Logistic_Enabled_Number__c =0;
        insert aa;
        aa.Merchant_Engagement__c = 'High Engaged';
        aa.Merchant_Webstore_Status__c = 'High Progress';
        update aa;

        Account aaa=new Account();
        aaa.LastName='TestAcc1';
        aaa.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        aaa.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-1;
        aaa.Login_Log_Count_0_30__c = 2;
        insert aaa;
        aaa.Merchant_Engagement__c = 'Medium Engaged';
        update aaa;

        Account a1=new Account();
        a1.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a1.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a1.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-2;
        insert a1;

        task t1=new task();
        t1.whatid=a1.id;
        t1.Status='In Progress';
        insert t1;

        Account a2=new Account();
        a2.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a2.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a2.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-7;
        insert a2;

        task t2=new task();
        t2.whatid=a2.id;
        t2.Status='In Progress';
        insert t2;

        Account a3=new Account();
        a3.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a3.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a3.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-14;
        insert a3;

        task t3=new task();
        t3.whatid=a3.id;
        t3.Status='In Progress';
        insert t3;

        Account a4=new Account();
        a4.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a4.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a4.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-21;
        insert a4;

        task t4=new task();
        t4.whatid=a4.id;
        t4.Status='In Progress';
        insert t4;

         Profile pf = [Select Id from Profile where Name = 'Standard User'];
         User u = new User();
            //u.FirstName = 'Test';
            u.LastName = 'Nicomatic2';
            u.Email = 'test987@gmail.com.sandbox';
            u.CompanyName = 'test.com';
            u.Title = 'Test User';
            u.Username = 'test987@gmail.com.sandbox';
            u.Alias = 'ni';
            u.CommunityNickname = 'ni';
            u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Mexico_City';
            u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
            u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
            u.ProfileId = pf.Id;
            u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';       
            insert u;

        Account a5=new Account();
        a5.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a5.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a5.Payments_Enabled_Number__c =0;
        a5.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-7;
        a5.Domain_Name_Number__c = 0;
        a5.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = false;
        insert a5;

        task t5=new task();
        t5.whatid=a5.id;
        t5.Subject='Status check about - Domain Name';
        t5.OwnerId=u.id;
        t5.On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone';
        t5.Description = a5.Merchant_Segment_7__c;
        insert t5;  
        a5.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = true;
        update a5;

        Account a6=new Account();
        a6.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a6.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a6.Domain_Name_Number__c = 0;
        a6.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-14;
        a6.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = false;
        insert a6;

        task t6=new task();
        t6.whatid=a6.id;
        t6.Subject='How-to Email about - Domain Name';
        t6.OwnerId=u.id;
        t6.On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email';
        t6.Description = a6.Merchant_Segment_14__c;
        insert t6;  
        a6.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = true;
        update a6;  

        Account a7=new Account();
        a7.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a7.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a7.Domain_Name_Number__c =0;
        a7.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-21;
        a7.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = false;
        insert a7;

        task t7=new task();
        t7.whatid=a7.id;
        t7.Subject='Best Practices Email about - Domain Name';
        t7.OwnerId=u.id;
        t7.On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email';
        t7.Description = a7.Merchant_Segment_21__c;
        insert t7;  
        a7.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c = true;
        update a7;


        MerchantLifecycleSchedulerClass scheUpdate = new MerchantLifecycleSchedulerClass();
        String sch ='0 57 * * * ?';    //This will run at 57th minute of any given hour. 
        System.schedule('Schedule to update Account Name', sch,scheUpdate);          

        test.stopTest();        

     }  

     public static testMethod void TestMefordiffAges1(){
        test.startTest();

        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName1 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt1 = rtName1.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();


        Profile pf = [Select Id from Profile where Name = 'Standard User'];
        User u = new User();
        //u.FirstName = 'Test';
        u.LastName = 'Nicomatic2';
        u.Email = 'test987@gmail.com.sandbox';
        u.CompanyName = 'test.com';
        u.Title = 'Test User';
        u.Username = 'test987@gmail.com.sandbox';
        u.Alias = 'ni';
        u.CommunityNickname = 'ni';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Mexico_City';
        u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
        u.ProfileId = pf.Id;
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';       
        insert u;

        Account a5=new Account();
        a5.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a5.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a5.Payments_Enabled_Number__c =0;
        a5.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-7;
        a5.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = false;
        insert a5;

        task t5=new task();
        t5.whatid=a5.id;
        t5.Subject='Status check about - Payment Enabled';
        t5.OwnerId=u.id;
        t5.On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone';
        t5.Description = a5.Merchant_Segment_7__c;
        insert t5;  
        a5.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
        update a5; 

        Account a6=new Account();
        a6.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a6.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a6.Payments_Enabled_Number__c =0;
        a6.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-14;
        a6.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = false;
        insert a6;

        task t6=new task();
        t6.whatid=a6.id;
        t6.Subject='How-to Email about- Payment Enabled';
        t6.OwnerId=u.id;
        t6.On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email';
        t6.Description = a6.Merchant_Segment_14__c;
        insert t6;  
        a6.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
        update a6;

        Account a7=new Account();
        a7.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a7.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a7.Payments_Enabled_Number__c =0;
        a7.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-21;
        a7.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = false;
        insert a7;

        task t7=new task();
        t7.whatid=a7.id;
        t7.Subject='Best Practices Email about - Payment Enabled';
        t7.OwnerId=u.id;
        t7.On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Email';
        t7.Description = a7.Merchant_Segment_21__c;
        insert t7;  
        a7.Payment_Enabled_Checkbox__c = true;
        update a7;

        Account a8 = new Account();
        a8.LastName='TestAcc2';
        a8.RecordTypeId=rt1;
        a8.Logistic_Enabled_Number__c =0;
        a8.Subscription_Date_First__c=system.today()-7;
        a8.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c = false;
        insert a8;

        task t8=new task();
        t8.whatid=a8.id;
        t8.Subject='Status check about - Logistics Enabled';
        t8.OwnerId=u.id;
        t8.On_boarding_Channel__c = 'Phone';
        t8.Description = a8.Merchant_Segment_7__c;
        insert t8;  
        a8.Logistic_Enabled_Checkbox__c= true;
        update a8;
     }
}
```

Comment: if ever there was a class whose test data should be loaded from static resources, this is one; I'd also look hard and long at refactoring the class to use a lot fewer lines of code with maps to hold the various Task constructions

Answer (score 0):

This code could be so much clearer (and this is only one idea) ..

```
@TestVisible private enum TASKTYPE {FOO, BAR, ....};

// somewhere within the scope of acc1 ...
map<taskType,Task> taskTypeToTaskMap = new map<taskType,Task) {
             TASKTYPE.FOO => new Task(subject='foo',                        
                                      onboarding_channel__c = 'fooChannel',
                                      description = acc1.fld1__c),
             TASKTYPE.BAR => new Task(subject='bar',                        
                                      onboarding_channel__c = 'barChannel',
                                      description = acc1.fld2__c),
             ...};
Task t = taskToTypeMap.get(getTaskType(acc1));
t.whatid = acc1.id;
t.ownerId = acc1.ownerId;
lTask1.add(t);

@TestVisible private TASKTYPE getTaskType(Account a) {
  if(a.Domain_Name_Number__c == 0 && acc1.Subscription_Age__c == 7 && !acc1.Domain_Name_Checkbox__c) 
     return TASKTYPE.FOO
  else
  if (...next condition) return TASKTYPE.BAR
  else ...
}
```

Because of `@TestVisible`, you can verify the `getTaskType()` conditions in a testmethod simply by doing

```
system.assertEquals(MyClass.TASKTYPE.FOO,myCls.getTaskType(new Account(domain_Name_number__c = 0, subscription_age__c = 7, domain_name_check__c = false));
.. repeat for all other enums
```

and the main method can be verified/code covered simply by mocking a single Account.

Now, that said ... while the structure of the above is easy to follow and maintain, one could argue that one should have asserts to verify that the maps were set up properly and in that case, you'll need to mock a bunch of Accounts.

There is also a small performance penalty at reconstructing the maps for each Account